# How to select dataframe columns using string keys when the column names are timestamps?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, timestamp

In pandas, time series can be indexed by passing a string that is interpretable as a date. This works for a DataFrame too:

```
>>> dates = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=8, freq='M')
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
>>> df
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-31  0.096115  0.069723 -1.546733 -1.661178
2000-02-29  0.256296  1.838310  0.227132  1.765269
2000-03-31  0.315862  0.167007 -1.340888  1.005260
2000-04-30  1.238728 -2.325420  1.371134 -0.373232
2000-05-31  0.639211 -0.209961 -1.006498  0.005214
2000-06-30  0.091590 -0.664554 -2.037539 -1.335070
2000-07-31  0.275373 -0.398758  0.402848  0.441035
2000-08-31  2.189259 -1.236159 -0.579680  0.878355
>>> df['2000-05']
                   A         B         C         D
2000-05-31  0.639211 -0.209961 -1.006498  0.005214
```

I am looking for ways to do this when the timestamps are the column names.

```
>>> df = df.T
>>> df['2000-05']
```

This yields `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`. The same is true for

```
>>> df.loc[:, '2000-05']
```

The most immediate solution that I can think of is

```
>>> df.T['2000-05'].T
   2000-05-31
A    0.639211
B   -0.209961
C   -1.006498
D    0.005214
```

but I am wondering if there are any other good solutions. I imagine that for very large DataFrames, doing transpositions may have a performance impact that could be avoided here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there *is* always the `filter` option.

```
df = df.T
df.filter(like='2000-05')

   2000-05-31
A    1.884517
B    0.258133
C    0.809360
D   -0.069186
```

`filter` gives you greater flexibility, for example, with regular expressions:

```
df.filter(regex='2000-.*-30')

   2000-04-30  2000-06-30
A   -2.968870    2.064582
B   -0.844370    0.093393
C    0.027328    0.033193
D   -0.270860   -0.455323
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try `str` , `contains`

```
df[df.index.str.contains('2000-05')].T
Out[163]: 
   2000-05-31
A    0.639211
B   -0.209961
C   -1.006498
D    0.005214
```

Comment: When I try this, I am getting `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')`

Answer (score 1):

There's also [`truncate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html), which allows you to work with datetime objects instead of treating the column names as strings.

This would require two dates, though - `before` and `after` arguments act as bookends for the period you want to retain.

```
df_t = df.T
df_t.columns = pd.to_datetime(df_t.columns)

df_t.truncate(after="2000-03", before="2000-02", axis=1)

   2000-02-29
A    0.256296
B    1.838310
C    0.227132
D    1.765269
```

Comment: This seems to work with `after="2000-06", before="2000-05"` as parameters for the original example.